# Saved X, y data in scikit-learn estimator

Tags: python, scikit-learn

It seems to me that the data, when fit, is not saved on estimators. I am subclassing the `BaseEstimator` class and am wondering the following:

- Is there a reason the underlying data is not copied/saved when the estimator calls `.fit()`?
- If I *do* copy the data to a `self.X`/`self.y` property on my subclass, is that something I will later regret?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `sklearn` [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html),

> Note that the model is fitted using X and y, but the object holds no
>   reference to X and y. There are, however, some exceptions to this, as
>   in the case of precomputed kernels where ***this data must be stored for***
>   ***use by the predict method.***

The reason why the data is not stored is because,
in general, once the estimator is fitted, the data itself will not be used anymore.

Whether you would later regret on copying the data to properties depends on multiple things: requirments on the application, use-case, size of the data to name a few.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the information, that's great. I had a feeling the "size of the data" issue would be an explanation, I do seem to recall that data gets copied/stored in linear regressions in R tho so I figured this was worth asking about on stack overflow